# Split String of numbers into array of digits

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String as

```
String s = "3457456433";
```

I want to generate an array of the numbers as

```
[3,4,5,7,4,5,6,4,3,3]
```

I tried using

```
String [] numbers = s.split("\\D+");
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Which regex should I use in order to get the desired result?

Comment: Split on `""` (empty string) - that will split it into characters. But if you're working with digits you might want to use `.toCharArray()`.

Comment: Yes try this String[] stringArray = s.split(""); System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringArray));